# when adding new height to wrapper my screen jumps to the top of the page

Tags: jquery, animation

I have a wwebpage with Header-Content-Footer. In the content i Have a wrapper and in this wrapper i got a form who is extending itself. When i extend the form i change the min-height of the wrapper so that the footer will go below the wrapper. This  and i use this jquery code for that:

```
$('#formWrapper').animate({'min-height':totalHeight}, { duration: 400, queue: false });
```

now everytime i click a button it will extend this wrapper with an animation. But when it goes animate then my screen will go the the top and i myself cannot see the animation. How can i keep the focus on that part of the screen where the animation is happening?

Thank you

button:

```
<td colspan="3" id="todu2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" id="newItemBoxButton" ><img src="images/addicon.png" /> Voeg een nieuwe regel toe</a></td>
```

handler:

```
var tdCount =1;
var hiddenCount =1;
$("#newItemBoxButton").click(function(){
            tdCount++;
            hiddenCount++;
            $("#addNewRowAfterThisRow" ).before( "<tr id='itemBox"+tdCount+"'><td valign='top' nowrap='nowrap' class='style1' width='10'>"+tdCount+"</td><td valign='top' ><textarea name='item"+tdCount+"' id='item2"+tdCount+"' rows='4' cols='70' placeholder='Item'></textarea></td><td>&nbsp;</td><td valign='top' class='style3new'><input class='amountBox' type='text' id='amount"+tdCount+"' name='amount"+tdCount+"' value='' placeholder='0' /></td><td  valign='top' class='style3new'> <a href='#' class='deleteItemBoxButton' style='vertical-align:middle' ><img src='images/deleteicon.png'  /></a></td></tr>" );

    //add formheight with 120px < which is the total height of 1 TR
var fieldsetHeight = document.getElementById("fieldset2").offsetHeight;
var totalHeight = fieldsetHeight + 120;
    $('#formWrapper').animate({'min-height':totalHeight}, { duration: 400, queue: false });

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------> HIER BEN JE GEBLEVEN DE SCREEN JUMPT STEEDS NAAR  DE TOP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32268336/when-adding-new-height-to-wrapper-my-screen-jumps-to-the-top-of-the-page
});
```

Comment: I suspect that it's the button that does that. What does the code look like for the button and handling the event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options to fix this.

Replace `href="#"` by `href="javascript: void(0);"`. The `#` is used for in-page-navigation, meant to be followed by an element that has the id `#element-id`. Since it is empty, it simply refers to the document itself, making it jump to the top.

Alternatively, you can either add a `return false;` at the end of your click handler function, or use jQuery's `preventDefault();`:

```
$("#newItemBoxButton").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // default click action is prevented
```

> http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Answer (score 1):

Just as I expected, the button is what's sending you to the top of the page.

The `href="#"` is the empty bookmark, which is at the top of the page. It's the equivalent of placing a bookmark anchor at the top of the page and using its name in the link.

You can easily stop the default action of the link using the `preventDefault` method:

```
$("#newItemBoxButton").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  ...
```